# No ExceptionInfo being passed to after_return handler in celery

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celeryd, python-billiard

Based on documentation, this handler is supposed to be called after the task returns.
The `einfo` argument refers to the ExceptionInfo instance, the definition for which is found at http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/_modules/billiard/einfo.html

I was under the impression that `after_return` will have an `einfo` passed in IF the task has erred for any reason.

But when I tested it, seems like `einfo` is always None. So looks like I am missing something.

Does anyone know under what circumstances will this `einfo` be made available to `after_return`? I want to use some attributes on this object in the after_return handler.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug, I found that `after_return` is always get invoked with `einfo = None`, [github](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/a6453043fbfa676cca22c4945f3f165ce8eb4ec0/celery/app/trace.py#L472). It is probably worth reporting about the issue